# How to deploy ml model in AWS S3, take input from another S3 and output the prediction?

Tags: amazon-web-services, machine-learning, amazon-s3

I have a pre-trained ml model that is stored in an AWS S3 bucket, whenever an input file if uploaded in another S3 bucket, the ml model should run using the input and output the prediction into another S3 bucket.

I tried to use AWS lambda and add a trigger for S3 input bucket, that is whenever a file in uploaded into the bucket the lambda function gets triggered and should get the model. Now I have some issues -

```
1. Not able to use pandas and other libraries in python.
2. How to call the ml model stored in the bucket.
3. Later I have to implement it in R as well.
4. I have a windows machine and cannot download CLI.
5. I have more model to deploy, so can't totally reply on lambda I guess.
```

Now is there any other better and easy way to approach this like using other AWS services available. I am allowed to use any services irrespective of the price.

I tried searching on the net to upload pandas dependencies and others but failed to do so. It shows 'Nota able to upload lambda function'.

Comment: Whoa! You have so many questions in there! There seem to be [some articles](https://www.google.com/search?q=aws+lambda+pandas) about using Pandas with AWS Lambda. You can download the AWS CLI for Windows at https://aws.amazon.com/cli/.